# Removing duplicate rows with row_number issue

Tags: duplicates, row-number

I have used the following to remove duplicates, however i am not getting the behaviour i expect.

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT
    SLA.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SLA.WorkItemDimKey ORDER BY SLA.UpdatedBatchId DESC) AS seqnum
  FROM dbo.SLAInstanceInformationFactvw SLA) SLA_Remove_Duplicates
  ON WorkItemDimvw.WorkItemDimKey = SLA_Remove_Duplicates.WorkItemDimKey
    AND SLA_Remove_Duplicates.seqnum =1
```

I need to use the Order DESC tag to get the duplicate with the largest value of UpdateBatchId. This works great on items that have duplications, however items that do not have duplicates are also excluded.
If i change the Order to ASC (default), it returns all single items plus filtered duplicates, but i get the wrong duplicate (one with the lowest UpdateBatchId).
Would greatly appreciate any help.